# How to use php-function-output as input for javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, function

I have a php-function `trans` to translate text. How to input `trans`-output in javascript?

```
<script>
function fregister_submit(f) {
    if (!f.agree.checked) {
        alert("<?=trans('회원가입약관의 내용에 동의하셔야 회원가입 하실 수 있습니다.')?>");
        f.agree.focus();
        return false;
    }

    if (!f.agree2.checked) {
        alert("개인정보처리방침안내의 내용에 동의하셔야 회원가입 하실 수 있습니다.");
        f.agree2.focus();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don’t understand your question ... what PHP would you need in JavaScript? ... What I see above, doesn’t look like PHP.

Comment: i want to input function <?php trans('...') ?> but i dont know how to input that

Comment: You need to show us that `<?php trans('...') ?>` ... I'm guessing, that what you really are asking, is *How to translate php-function to JS-function* ... but how would I know from above description???

Comment: Mmmm... Is it `"<?=trans('회원...` ... you want to insert the results from a php-function, as argument for your JS-alert???

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alert("<? echo trans('회원가입약관의 내용에 동의하셔야 회원가입 하실 수 있습니다.'); ?>");
```

Comment: how about this

if (!confirm("<?=trans('선택한 게시물을 정말')?> "+document.pressed+" <?=trans('하시겠습니까?\n\n한번 삭제한 자료는 복구할 수 없습니다')?>")) {
   return false;
  }

how to input the function

Comment: `if (!confirm("<? echo trans('선택한 게시물을 정말'); ?> "+document.pressed+" <? echo trans('하시겠습니까?\n\n한번 삭제한 자료는 복구할 수 없습니다'); ?>")) { return false; }`

Answer (score 0):

Converting php variables to be readable for javascript can be done like this:

```
<?php echo json_encode($var); ?>;
```

Everything else a simple echo does the job